# How can i disable Rubocop corrections?

Tags: rubocop

I have a conditional like this, first i am using 'blank' i dont want to use 'present', but rubocop is changing that conditional, how can i dont allow to do to rubocop?

```
unless color.blank?
```

But when i typed `rubocop -a`

That is appering

```
if color.present?
```

i dont want what rubocop change that like of code, only that line, are there some to dissable rubocop only for that line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rubocop can be configured](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/1.41/configuration.html). You can turn cops on and off, and you can configure them. The message from Rubocop tells you what the particular cop's name is. That one is [Rails/Present](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop-rails/cops_rails.html#railspresent).

You can also [turn off cops for individual lines](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/1.41/configuration.html#disabling-cops-within-source-code).

```
# rubocop:disable Rails/Present
unless color.blank?
# rubocop:enable Rails/Present
```

However, unless you have a particularly good reason to, it's better to avoid turning off rubocop line by line. Let Rubocop do its thing and configure it instead.